# Calculating the length of A* Algorithm path

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to calculate the length of the generated path from A* algorithm. Therefore, 
I'm assuming that each pixel is a rectangle area of pixel_width * pixel_length, then I can measure traveled distance by accumulating the distance between pixel center whenever the algorithm decides the next pixel to take.

In my code, there is also elevation, so this means in line 173 I inserted something like below,

```
path_length += math.sqrt((x2-x)**2+(y2-y)**2+(e2-elevation1[x][y])**2)
```

[image: A*]

After applying it, I got this number `123630.43677339483`. Is this logical? Any ideas?

## The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#grid format
# 0 = navigable space
# 1 = occupied space

import random
import math
import time

grid = [[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(100)]for j in range(100)]

# clear starting and end point of potential obstacles
grid[2][2] = 0
grid[95][95] = 0



init = [2,2]                            #Start location is (5,5) which we put it in open list.
goal = [len(grid)-5,len(grid[0])-5]     #Our goal in (40,38) and here are the coordinates of the cell.

heuristic = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
for i in range(len(grid)):    
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):            
        heuristic[i][j] = abs(i - goal[0]) + abs(j - goal[1])

plt.plot(0,10)
plt.plot(0,-len(grid)-10)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis("equal")

plt.plot([-1, len(grid[0])],[[-x/2 for x in range(-1,len(grid)*2+1)], [-y/2 for y in range(-1,len(grid)*2+1)]], ".k")
plt.plot([[x/2 for x in range(-2,len(grid[0])*2+1)],[x/2 for x in range(-2,len(grid[-1])*2+1)]],[1, -len(grid)],".k")

plt.plot(init[1],-init[0],"og")
plt.plot(goal[1],-goal[0],"ob")


#Below the four potential actions to the single field


delta =      [[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [-1, 0, 1],
              [0, -1, 1],
              [-1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [-1, 1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, -1, math.sqrt(2)],
              [1, 1, math.sqrt(2)]]



delta_name = ['V','>','<','^','//','\\','\\','//']

cost = 1   #Each step costs you one

drone_height = 60

kg = 0.6
ke = 1
kh = 0.8

penalty1 = 10
penalty2 = 1.5


risk = [i for i in range(50,60)]

def search():

    pltx,plty=[],[]
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y]

    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    action = [[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1
    expand=[[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    elevation1 = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    for i in range(len(grid)):    
        for j in range(len(grid[0])):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                elevation1[i][j] = random.randint(1,100)
                if elevation1[i][j] >= drone_height:
                    plt.plot(j,-i,".k", markersize=10)
                elif elevation1[i][j] in risk:
                    plt.plot(j,-i,".r", markersize=10)
                else:
                    plt.plot(j,-i,"sm")
            else:
                elevation1[i][j] = 0

    elevation2 = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    for i in range(len(elevation1)):
        for j in range(len(elevation1[0])):

            if elevation1[i][j] >= drone_height:
                elevation2[i][j] = elevation1[i][j]*penalty1
            elif elevation1[i][j] in risk:
                elevation2[i][j] = elevation1[i][j]*penalty2
            else:
                elevation2[i][j] = elevation1[i][j]


    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    path_length = 0
    #h = heuristic[x][y]
    h = math.sqrt((x - goal[0])**2 + (y - goal[1])**2)
    e = elevation2[x][y]
    f = kg*g + kh*h + ke*e

    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[f, g, h, x, y]]

    '''
  We are going to use two flags
  1- found and it will be True when the goal position is found.
  2- resign it will be True if we couldn't find the goal position and explore everything.
  '''
    found  = False   #flag that is set when search complete
    resign = False   #Flag set if we can't find expand
    count = 0

    t1 = time.time()
    while found is False and resign is False:

        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open) == 0:    #If our open list is empty, there is nothing to expand.
            resign = True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
            print()
        else:
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()             #sort elements in an increasing order from the smallest g value up
            open.reverse()          #reverse the list
            next = open.pop()       #remove the element with the smallest g value from the list

            #Then we assign the three values to x,y and g. Which is our expantion.
            x = next[3]
            y = next[4]
            g = next[1]
            expand[x][y] = count
            count+=1

            #Check if we are done
            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this "if".
                print('############## Search is success')
                print()

            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)):       #going through all our actions the four actions
                    #We apply the actions to x and y with additional delta to construct x2 and y2
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]
                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:

                        #if x2 and y2 not checked yet and there is not obstacles
                        #if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and elevation[x2][y2] < drone_height and elevation[x2][y2] not in risk:
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g + cost             #we increment the cose
                            #h2 = heuristic[x2][y2]
                            h2 = math.sqrt((x2 - goal[0])**2 + (y2 - goal[1])**2)
                            e2 = elevation2[x2][y2]
                            f2 = kg*g2 + kh*h2 + ke*e2
                            path_length+=math.sqrt((x2-x)**2+(e2-elevation1[x][y])**2)

                            open.append([f2,g2,h2,x2,y2])
                            #we add them to our open list
                            pltx.append(y2)
                            plty.append(-x2)
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
                            action[x2][y2] = i
    t2 = time.time()
    runtime = t2-t1
    print('The elapsed time= ',runtime)
    print()
    print(path_length)
    print(len(pltx))
    print(len(plty))

    policy=[[' ' for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    x=goal[0]
    y=goal[1]
    policy[x][y]='*'
    visx = [y]
    visy = [-x]
    while x !=init[0] or y !=init[1]:
        x2=x-delta[action[x][y]][0]
        y2=y-delta[action[x][y]][1]
        policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]
        x=x2
        y=y2
        visx.append(y)
        visy.append(-x)


    # visualization
    for x in range(0,len(pltx),20):
        plt.plot(pltx[:x],plty[:x],"xc")
        plt.pause(0.001)

    plt.plot(visx,visy, "-r")

    plt.show()

search()
```

Comment: *"Is this logical?"* What's the distance between the start and end point of your path? How does it compare to the computed length of your path? Are the two values unreasonably different, or does your result look realistic?

Comment: @GPhilo My dear. I just need to calculate the length of the path. The environment size is 100x100 and the obstacles are generated randomly. I didn't get your question. I just want to calculate the length of the path and I'm not 100% sure about what I did.

Comment: I'm just asking follow-up questions, as the question as it is currently stated can't quite be answered with the given information. You don't give the start and end points, so let's assume (0,0) and (100,100). The euclidean 2D distance between the two is `100*2**(1/2)`, which is about 141, without considering elevation. Given this premise, the shape of the found path and without running your code -or looking too hard into it, as I can't test it anyway- I'd say `123630` is way off.

Comment: @GPhilo The start point at (2,2) and end point at (95,95).